# version=%version: =% - is there a good reason for using this?

Tags: batch-file

I am dealing with some code that was put together by someone who has long since left the company.  It reads:

```
REM         XX.XXX      YYYYMMDD Author Description 
REM version=4.3   &:20170418 comment comment comment 
REM version=4.4   &:20170519 comment comment comment
SET version=4.5c  &:20170604 comment comment comment
SET "version=%version: =%"
```

After puzzling through this, we finally figured out two things: one, that the & thing works to tell DOS that a new command is coming in the same line, and then the :date just gets thrown out because DOS doesn't know what to do with it.

But then we get to this SET "version=%version: =%" nonsense.

All I've been able to deduce from it so far is that it will remove spaces, so that if I did this instead:

```
SET version=4.5 c
SET "version=%version: =%"
ECHO %version%
```

I'll get "4.5c" echoed to the screen.

I can't find any information about this ": =%" business anywhere online.  Is there a good reason to be doing this?

Comment: If it's nonsense why do you care? Read through `Set /?` in a cmd window or [view online](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) BTW the 1st set in your example isn't double quoted and will create trailing space in the version string, the 2nd command which **IS** double quoted removes them.

Comment: mind that (with that syntax), `%version%` will have 2 or 3 spaces *at the end*, which will be removed. Note: a better syntax would be `set "version=4.4"  20180110 comment` (note the position of the quotes). (In the original code,`:20170604` and every thing after will be ignored (technically it's a label; not a good coding practice to use labels as comments) In the code in this comment, the quotes define what should go to the variable. Everything after the closing quotes is ignored, so there is no need for `&` - questionable coding practice, more readable: `set "var=value" & REM comment`))

Comment: By the way, a small nit-pick: you're not using DOS. DOS died back in the 80s. You're using the Windows Command Processor, a.k.a. cmd.exe. It may look a bit like the old DOS, but is actually very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What Is Going On?:**

This looks like **Variable Edit/Replace** or in other terms [syntax-replacement](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html). What this allows you to do is take a string, and replace characters or words from it and either replace the existing string or create a new modified one.

Taking example `SET "version=%version: =%"` This will be modifying the string `version` and removing all spaces from the string.

**Positives To This Method:**

Being that some strings or code need to be modified, you can very conveniently use a pure batch option to *replace words in text files*, *remove words from string*, *add commas after words*, and even *remove the last **x** characters in a string*.

syntax-replacement is commonly used for issues that that cannot be solved within a for loop or strings that need to be tweaked before being used, an example will be folder paths. In `for` loops, when processing strings containing `\` and trying to use the `delims=\`, you sometimes need to change it to a less conflicting character as `;` - `SET "String=%String:\=;"`. The uses are endless.

**Negatives To This Method:**

This is a very easy way to edit strings but can come with a negative being that you cannot edit strings with special characters without first using an `^` to escape special characters in the base string. An Example of this will be the following:

- `SET "version=Hello & There"` - This will break the syntax-replacement code as `&`
  is calling a new command.
- `SET "version=Hello ^& There"` - This is the proper way to "ignore" the `&` symbol
  for processing.

---

Check out `Set /?` in a CMD window for more information.

Comment: The quotes are protecting the special characters.  So you do not need to escape the ampersand.  Run these three commands from the cmd prompt: 1) `SET "version=Hello & There"` 2) `set "version=%version:There=Bye%"` 3) `set version`. The output will be: `version=Hello & Bye`.